# How to understand MTA's real-time gtfs data feeds

Tags: java, android, gtfs, mta

So far I've filled out the [MTA online registration form](http://web.mta.info/developers/index.html) for a Developer's API Key. Then in my android project, I implemented the gtfs realtime bindings dependecy from one of [Google's github repositories](https://github.com/google/gtfs-realtime-bindings/tree/master/java),

```
compile group: 'com.google.transit', name: 'gtfs-realtime-bindings', version: '0.0.4'
```

Using their Java class, I tried this following code to print out all the gtfs data from the link given by MTA,

```
try {
    String urlString = "http://datamine.mta.info/mta_esi.php?key=insertmykeyhere";
    URL url = new URL(urlString.toString());
    GtfsRealtime.FeedMessage feed = GtfsRealtime.FeedMessage.parseFrom(url.openStream());
    for (GtfsRealtime.FeedEntity entity : feed.getEntityList()) {
        if (entity.hasTripUpdate()) {
            Log.d("stuff", entity.getTripUpdate().toString());
        } 
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, I'm now having trouble interpreting the data printed out. I understand that there are static data feeds from http://web.mta.info/developers/developer-data-terms.html, which I used to interpret some of the data. Here is one of the trip updates printed out,

```
stuff: trip {
    trip_id: "036000_GS.N01R"
    start_date: "20170218"
    route_id: "GS"
    1001: "\n\0200S 0600  GCS/TSS\020\001\030\001"
}     
stop_time_update {
    departure {
        time: 1487415600
    }
    stop_id: "901N"
    1001: "\n\0011\022\0011"
}
stop_time_update {
    arrival {
        time: 1487415690
    }
    stop_id: "902N"
    1001: "\n\0011"
}
```

I understand some parts such as trip_id, start_date, and stop_id. But parts such as trip_id, time, and 1001 I'm still unsure about it and the text files from the static feed don't do the best job of explaining them.

Answer (score 1):

The MTA Subway GTFS-RT feeds are a little different than most others.

Typically, GTFS-RT refers directly back to a static GTFS' via trip_id/stop_id/etc. Since in NYC there is usually a deviation from normal service ("2 Train via the 5 Line"), the RT feed retains the option to create new trips that do not exist in the static feed.

To answer your immediate questions, you need to add the [realtime extensions](http://datamine.mta.info/sites/all/files/pdfs/nyct-subway.proto.txt). That should solve the empty [1001](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/guides/extensions#ExtensionRegistry): field.

To do so, either compile the proto file, or just import the [onebusaway-gtfs-realtime-api](https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-gtfs-realtime-api/) library, which has the extensions pre-compiled in:

```
    ExtensionRegistry registry = ExtensionRegistry.newInstance();
    registry.add(GtfsRealtimeNYCT.nyctFeedHeader);
    registry.add(GtfsRealtimeNYCT.nyctStopTimeUpdate);
    registry.add(GtfsRealtimeNYCT.nyctTripDescriptor);

   GtfsRealtime.FeedMessage feed = GtfsRealtime.FeedMessage.parseFrom(url.openStream(), registry);
```

This gives a result like:

```
trip {
  trip_id: "B20170217WKD_132800B..S"
  start_date: "2017-02-17 22:08:00"
  route_id: "B"
  [transit_realtime.nyct_trip_descriptor] {
    train_id: "1B 2208 145/BBC"
    is_assigned: true
    direction: SOUTH
  }
}
stop_time_update {
  arrival {
    time: 1487390920
  }
  departure {
    time: 1487390920
  }
  stop_id: "D39"
  schedule_relationship: SCHEDULED
  [transit_realtime.nyct_stop_time_update] {
    scheduled_track: "A3"
    actual_track: "A3"
  }
}
stop_time_update {
  arrival {
    time: 1487391130
  }
  departure {
    time: 1487391130
  }
  stop_id: "D40"
  schedule_relationship: SCHEDULED
  [transit_realtime.nyct_stop_time_update] {
    scheduled_track: "A3"
    actual_track: "A3"
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the result of the code using the onebusaway api? I'm not too familiar with the library.

Comment: the onebusaway library is just the protobuf compiled with the required extension. See the trip_descriptor is now filled in.
https://github.com/laidig/nyct-gtfs-rt-example has a working Maven project to try out with.

Comment: hello, it's been a while since i've seen this answer so I just noticed the edit. I'm kinda new to Maven so how would I install the github repo? Would I just download the repo and then upload it in some IDE like Eclipse?

Comment: If you have eclipse and the Maven plugin installed, just file->import>Maven